# TestStack White doesn't detect an SEHException

Tags: c++, winforms, unmanaged, white-framework, seh

I'm writing a few tests for a managed/unmanaged Winform application. Some of the bugs occur in the unmanaged part, and result in the process terminating due to an unhandled `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException` exception .

When this exception occurs, Windows pops up a message box explaining the error.

Unfortunately, neither MS Test nor White recognize this. The test itself finishes successfully without any sign of error, even though I can see the message box pop up right before the test goes on and closes the application.

How can I detect this kind of exception?

Comment: Pretty vague, Windows does not show a message box.  Using the debugger would be advisable, at least you can show a stack trace.

Comment: I don't want to debug the code, I want the unit test to figure out something bad has happened.

Comment: Hmm, fairly pointless to use unit tests if you don't want to find out what is wrong with code.  Well, test failed, nasty exceptions should not be reported with a message box.  Happens all the time anyway.  Write a bug report and let the programmer figure it out.

Comment: That's the point. I *want* the test to fail, so that the code can later be debugged. Unfortunately, the test succeeds. The tests do fail with a managed exception is raised. The unmanaged exception is not caught, the process running the Winforms application is still alive, and there's no indication that something bad has happened.

Comment: The message box is not displayed by the application. It is the standard "Unhandled exception has occured in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error...." .

Answer (score 0):

The message box is the result of the default unhandled exception handling of a Winforms application.

I ended up looking for it after the test has finished. If the message box is there, I fail the test.